# Run MYSQL query upon modal popup

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, modal-dialog

I've a button in my code which onclick runs a javascript & pop-ups a modal.
I've been trying to execute a mysql query every time the modal pops up.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Here's the code for more help

```
<button class="art-button" id='.$id.'>Generate Reciept</button>
   <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    </br><button id="print" class="art-button" onClick="PrintContent('myModal');collect();">Print</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var btn = document.getElementById(<?php echo $id?>);
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
    confirm('Collect RS <?php echo $total?> From <?php echo $mem_nm?>?');
    alert("Fine of RS <?php echo $total ?>Collected Successfully From <?php echo $mem_nm?>");
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function PrintContent(myModal) {
    var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById(myModal);
    var WindowObject = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');

    $('#print').remove();
    WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
    WindowObject.document.close();
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();
    WindowObject.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't call php methods from the client. You will need to make some REST Calls to your backend where it will processteh MYSQL Query and send back.

Answer (score 0):

Make an AJAX request to grab data from database when you click on button that opens modal window.

Comment: well thanks, but I don't know much about AJAX, can you show me the syntax for that?

Comment: I suggest you to learn vanila javascript first then you can start learning jQuery. :)

Comment: Should be a comment

Comment: @Parvez Khan it is better to user `jquery ajax` because it is very easy with less coding . if you want i can add the your similar kind example here.

Comment: I insist, Plz :)

Comment: @Parvez Khan i have posted my answere below

Answer (score 0):

You need [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) data from you website and after catching data,open your modal like this:

```
$.get( "[your page address]", function( data ) {
  //Open your desired window here
  //or even make decision based on data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Parvez Khan so here is a similar kind of example . When a user clicks on button is opens a model the request is sent throught `AJAX` and the `PHP` file runs the `SQL query` the result will be sent back and displayed in the model with jquery.

These is HTML code with jquery script

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Model Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="display_details">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>

//JUERY SCRIPT
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();

        //THIS IS JQUERY AJAX METHOD
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'get_details.php',
            data:{get_details:1},
            success:function(data){
                $("#display_details").html(data); //the data is displayed in id=display_details
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is PHP file code:

```
 <?php
    $link = new mysqli('localhost','root','','demo');

    if($link->connect_error){
        die ("Connection failed".$link->connect_error);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['get_details']) && isset($_POST['get_details'])==1){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";

        if($res = $link->query($sql)){
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
                <p>employee Name : <?php echo $row['employee_name'];?></p>
                <p>Employee Salary : <?php echo $row['employee_salary'];?></p>
                <p>Employee age : <?php echo $row['employee_age'];?></p>
        <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error".$link->error;
        }
    }
?>
```

THIS IS THE IMAGE OF OUTPUT SHOWING DATA RECEIVE VIA AJAX 
[image: OUTPUT IMAGE]

websites to learn jquery ajax

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)

[tutorails point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/)

[javatutorial point](https://www.javatpoint.com/ajax-tutorial)

### If you like my answere give a Tick and click on top arrow